# Delphi 2010/XE2 MDI Example - Missing Code

Tags: delphi, mdi

When you wish to create a new application and click on MDI, Delphi creates a basic MDI application for you with the basic menu items and graphics.  You can run the program and create children windows and using the Window menu item place the children in cascade, tile, etc. arrangements.

My question is: where is the code to perform these operations?

I am stumped. You open the pas file editor and basically nothing is there. How does it do it?

Answer (score 6):

Each menu item is linked to different types descendants of `TWindowsAction=class(TAction)`. For example `WindowsCascadeItem` menu item is linked to `WindowsCascade1:TWindowsCascade(=class(TWindowAction))` action. So code is hidden in this class implementation in VCL\STDActns.PAS.